# Python multiple lists, keep identical, replace differences with variable

Tags: python, list, compare, levenshtein-distance

I want to compare an undefined amount of lists with the same length and create a new list of the same length, in the same order, where the identical places are kept and the ones not are replaced with a variable.

So the new list looks like ['a','b',variable1,'d']

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi there, could you show us your current code, as well as the stack trace for the error, where it is occurring and so on. I am not personally able to answer your question but I am sure having the above mentioned information will help those people who are trying to answer you. Please take a look here for further information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> lsts = [
...     [1,2,3,4],
...     [1,2,3,5],
...     [2,2,3,4]]
>>>
>>> results = []
>>> for col in zip(*lsts):
...     if not all(x == col[0] for x in col):
...         results.append('x')
...     else:
...         results.append(col[0])
...
>>> results
['x', 2, 3, 'x']
```

Replace `'x'` with the variable you want.

Comment: Just found out that the lists are actually not the same length by one or two positions. Sorry. Can you work something out to create a string from matching partial strings? After that filling up the different partial string with the variable will also try.

Comment: Do you want to truncate by the minimum length or pad (maybe with None) to the maximum length?

Comment: truncate by minimum length (246)

Comment: @LucaReichelt Sorry but I don't quite understand. What do you mean by matching partial strings?

Comment: Guess it changes the question, so I will mark it as solved. But as the lists of charcaters/strings, don't match in length, I will now have to look at partial strings inside the strings to find matches and fill the gaps in between them with the variable.

Comment: @LucaReichelt Then that would be a much more complicated question. In the case where you don't know the amount of difference beforehand, one possible solution is to compute [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) but that takes O(n^2) time so maybe you could also consider dealing with the data generation side.

Comment: actually tried levenshtein for quite some time but somehow the import won't work. Doesn't matter the environment. But I guess it's back to that^^

Comment: @LucaReichelt Well in any case best of luck : )

Comment: I will iterate through the list of strings always comparing to the last result using: `mb = matching_blocks(editops(a,b), a, b)
print(''.join([a[x[0]:x[0]+x[2]] for x in mb]))`